# Resolve promise only after variable filled?

Tags: node.js, promise

From the code below i am trying to resolve the promise ONLY after games object has its data filled from the api loop if that makes sense but it keeps displaying empty:

```
{
    info: summoner,
    matchIds: {                               << used for loop below
        0: matchIds['matches'][0].matchId,
        1: matchIds['matches'][1].matchId,
        2: matchIds['matches'][2].matchId,
        3: matchIds['matches'][3].matchId,
        4: matchIds['matches'][4].matchId,
        5: matchIds['matches'][5].matchId,
        6: matchIds['matches'][6].matchId,
        7: matchIds['matches'][7].matchId,
        8: matchIds['matches'][8].matchId,
        9: matchIds['matches'][9].matchId
    }
}

var getMatches = function(summoner) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var opt = {};
        var games = {};                         << object needs to be filled
        for (var val in Object.keys(summoner['matchIds'])) {
            var match = summoner['matchIds'][val];
            opt.id = match;
            api.getMatchById(opt, function(err, game) {
                games[x] = game;
            })
        }
        console.log(games);
        resolve({games});
    });
    return promise;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is assuming that `api.getMatchById()` is synchronous, but it likely is not and thus the `for` loop completed before any of your `api.getMatchById()` calls complete, thus games is always empty when you resolve.  You will have to keep track of when all the `api.getMatchById()` calls are done and only resolve when that happens.

The best way to code this would be to promisify `api.getMatchById()` and then use `Promise.all()` to track when they are all done.  If you weren't going to do that, then you could create a manual counter:

```
var getMatches = function(summoner) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var cntr = 0;
        var opt = {};
        var games = {};
        var keys = Object.keys(summoner['matchIds']);
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
            var match = summoner['matchIds'][key];
            opt.id = match;
            api.getMatchById(opt, function(err, game) {
                // need some error handling here
                games[x] = game;
                ++cntr;
                // when all api calls are done, resolve
                if (cntr === keys.length) {
                    resolve({games});
                }
            })
        });
    });
};
```

Also, please don't ever use for/in to iterate the items of an array as it can be prone to problems.  In ES6, you can use for/of.  I used `.forEach()` here.

Comment: @Elevant - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Hello possible solution if use, not pure promises but `bluebird` library

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  const propsPromise = {};
  Object.keys(summoner['matchIds']).forEach(val => {
    const match = summoner['matchIds'][val];
    propsPromise[match] = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        api.getMatchById(opt, (err, game) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(game);
        });
    });});
    return Promise.props(propsPromise);
});
```

You out promise will be solved as soon as the object will be resolved with content.

Link to documentation - [Promise.props](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html)

Comment: you've misplaced your `return Promise.props(propsPromise);`